Is the electron pair in an orbital entangled?
In the video "Bird navigation: The Quantum Around You. Ep1", Dr. Andrea Morello seems to imply that the electron pairs in atomic orbitals are entangled and will exhibit properties of entanglement when separated. Is this correct?

This is the orbital diagram I learned in high school. By orbital I am referring to the pair of electrons in each cell. When I searched this question up I found journal articles about "orbital entanglement" but I could not discern if we meant the same thing.

Yes, they are.  The search terms that you're looking for are "singlet state" (in atomic physics) or "Bell pair" (in quantum information).  It would be rather difficult to extricate one without the other, move it somewhere else without entangling it somehow with the experimental control apparatus (this is the origin of "decoherence"), and then measure it, but you could in principle, and you'd observe entangley results if you did.
